# Automatically delegate implementing methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, proxy, mockito, delegation

Can I automatically delegate all calls to the methods of another instance that share the same interface?

I have a big class (I want to test) like this:

```
class MyClassUnderTest implements SomeInterface {
  public void anImportantMethod() {
  }
  @Override
  public void fromTheInterface() {
  }
  @Override
  public void fromTheInterface2() {
  }
  private void utilFunc() {}
}
```

It implements an interface

```
interface SomeInterface {
  void fromTheInterface();
  void fromTheInterface2();
}
```

Given that, during unittest I want to "hide" the methods inherited from the interface with different implementations. For that I wrote a utility class

```
class DebugSomeInterface implements SomeInterface {
  @Override public void fromTheInterface() { log.debug("1"); }
  @Override public void fromTheInterface2() { log.debug("2"); };
}
```

Now I need to "delegate" all possible calls to that implemenation. I do this by hand in by deriving from `MyClassUnderTest` my own class, delegating all calls to that:

```
class MyClassUnderTest_Mock extends MyClassUnderTest {
    DebugSomeInterface delegated = new DebugSomeInterface();

  @Override public void fromTheInterface() {
    delegated.fromTheInterface();
  }
  @Override public void fromTheInterface2() { 
    delegated.fromTheInterface2();
  };
```

Only, I have a lot of classes implementing `SomeInterface` and doing that by hand is tedious and error prone.

I would like an (half-)automated way for creating `MyClassUnderTest_Mock` instances, like `mock(...)` with Mockito does. Maybe something like

```
 MyClassUnderTest underTest = new MyClassUnderTest();
 DebugSomeInterface delegated = new DebugSomeInterface();
 MyClassUnderTest instance = mixin(underTest, SomeInterface.class, delegated);
```

This would maybe create a "proxy" `instance` that delegates all calls of methods from `SomeInterface` to `delegated` and the rest to `underTest`.

There is some mechanism with proxy objects in core Java, but I can not bring it all together.

Comment: You could spy(new MyClassUnderTest()) and then mock out the method(s) you want to provide behavior for

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public static <T, U extends T> U createProxy(U classUnderTest, Class<T> interfaceType, T debugImplementation)
        throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    U spy = Mockito.spy(classUnderTest);
    for (Method m : interfaceType.getMethods()) {
        Object[] params = new Object[m.getParameterTypes().length];
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            params[i] = Mockito.any();
        }
        Mockito.when(m.invoke(spy, params)).thenAnswer(new Delegate(debugImplementation, m));
    }
    return spy;
}

public static class Delegate implements Answer {
    private final Object delegate;

    private final Method delegateMethod;

    public Delegate(Object delegate, Method delegateMethod) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.delegateMethod = delegateMethod;
    }

    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        return delegateMethod.invoke(delegate, invocation.getArguments());
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
MyClassUnderTest underTest = new MyClassUnderTest();
DebugSomeInterface delegated = new DebugSomeInterface();
MyClassUnderTest instance = createProxy(underTest, SomeInterface.class, delegated);
```

This will work how you want it to but as a disclaimer I think it's a bad idea... Having to spy on an object under test and mocking out bits of an object under test should be a red flag... This is bad practice, you only need to do things like this when code complexity is higher than optimal and parts of your class should be split out into other classes. I've never stumbled across a situation like this where refactoring my logic wasn't the better solution...